# Does the IDEA Act require a private school to forward a request for testing to the public school?

Tags: united-states, education

My son has been attending a small private school attached to our church. About a year ago, we requested of his teacher/principal that he receive a Dyslexia screening. The teacher agreed to get that set up. Months later it still hadn't happened. It eventually came out that the teacher had been deliberately stalling getting the testing.

I know that this would be illegal in a public school setting. I also know that the IDEA Act requires the public schools to work with private schools to some extent. What is less clear from what I can find online is whether (and under what circumstances) the private school is required to work with the public school and the parents to facilitate this testing.

Note: In this case, testing was eventually accomplished and the private school did facilitate the testing once we asked the public school directly.

Answer (score 1):

The act applies to states and public agencies, per [34 CFR 300.1](https://www.ecfr.gov/current/title-34/subtitle-B/chapter-III/part-300/subpart-A), but can apply to private institutions if

> (1) Referred to or placed in private schools and facilities by that
> public agency; or
>
> (2) Placed in private schools by their parents under the provisions of
> [§300.148](https://www.ecfr.gov/current/title-34/subtitle-B/chapter-III/part-300/subpart-B/subject-group-ECFRc2669ba9c45f0d6/section-300.148)

but the responsibility for guaranteeing compliance rests with the local education agency (that is, you would complain to the relevant school district, who has the responsibility for providing special education).